# Simple goto page in a ListView in react-native

Tags: android, listview, react-native, navigator

How can I click on a row, and visit that thing, from a ListView.

I've wrapped everything in a Navigator.

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
  var routeId = route.id;
  if (routeId === 'SplashPage') {
   return (
      <SplashPage
      navigator={navigator} />
   );
  }
  if (routeId === 'App') {
    return (
      <App
      navigator={navigator} />
  );
 }
}
```

Simple enough, but when I render a list view in the app page, I can't seem to get the context correct of the row to pass props to.

```
render() {
   return (
  <Navigator
      renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
      navigator={this.props.navigator}/>
  );
}


renderScene(route, navigator) {
 render(
    // If I run this.profilePage() from here, it works
    <ListView
    dataSource={this.state.feed}
    renderRow={this._renderRow} // need to pass the navigator here somehow?
     />
  );
}

 _renderRow(feeditem){
   return (
     <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={this.profilePage}><Text>Test to click</Text>
    // Also tried {this.profilePage.bind(this)} - didnt work
     </TouchableOpacity>
   )
 }

 profilePage(){
   this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'ProfilePage',
      name: 'Profile',
   });
   //'this' however is always null
 }
```

How do I properly pass the navigator context to the Row??
Or am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have a `ProfilePage` routeId in your `renderScene` method to match the id.

Comment: I do, I just left the 12 other pages off, to make the code small.  And just to show the structure of my switch

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. Break the Navigator into it's own component, it will be a little easier to reason about imo.

Nav Component:

```
var Nav = React.createClass({

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var routeId = route.id;
    if (routeId === 'SplashPage') {
      return ( <SplashPage navigator={navigator} /> );
    }
    // MORE ROUTES BELOW
  }

  render() {
   return (
    <Navigator
      initialRoute={{ id: 0, component: List, name: 'List' }}
      renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
      navigator={navigator} />
    );
  }

})
```

List Component:

```
var List = React.createClass({

  _renderRow(feeditem){
   return (
      <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={ () => this.profilePage() }><Text>Test to click</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

 profilePage(){
   this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'ProfilePage',
      name: 'Profile',
   });
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.feed}
        renderRow={this._renderRow}
      />
   )
 }
})
```